# Set minimum height and width to WinForms content within WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, charts, contentcontrol

I have a WinForms chart that is being used within WPF.

I don't have any easy access to the WinForms chart code so I am trying to find a solution via the WPF .xaml code.

The content size is determined by the movement of the `GridSplitter`.

the problem is that there is probably somewhere within the WinForms chart a minimum height and that cause the WinForms chart to overlay my WPF window contents.

this is how I use the WinForms chart in WPF:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gui.Modules.Common.Chart.ChartSeriesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:attachedProperties="clr-namespace:Gui.Core.AttachedProperties;assembly=Gui.Core"
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Gui.Modules.Common" mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{x:Static common:DesignData.ChartSeriesViewModel}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             >
  <Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="ChartContentControl" attachedProperties:Win32Keeper.Control="{Binding Chart}"/>    
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: normal chart behavior - not overlay]

[image: overlay example]

Comment: try place chart control in a Viewbox

Comment: not familiar with the "attachedProperties" behavior but... Why are you putting a WinForms control into a WPF ContentControl? Why not use the WindowsFormsHost control?